# Control Sitefinity Cookie (Persionalization (sf-prs-ss, sf-prs-lu, sf-prs-vp, sf-prs-vu), sf-data-intell-subject)

Tags: cookies, sitefinity

Does any method provide by Sitefinity to control the Sitefinity cookie: sf-prs-ss, sf-prs-lu, sf-prs-vp, sf-prs-vu (Personalization module), sf-data-intell-subject?

I just found a manual script by Sitefinity about delete Personalization but not about re-init it.
https://community.progress.com/s/article/unused-cookies-show-up-as-in-use-in-chrome

We are using Sitefinity 14 and working in project about control cookie: we choose Civic cookie with GTM.

Thanks!

Solution control cookie by Sitefinity

Answer (score 2):

The cookies are automatically managed by Sitefinity's tracking consent. As long as you follow that approach, you don't need to manually re-init them.

```
// The next code line is just a sample illustrating the general flow of your site logic. Do not use it in production.
// Instead, obtain user consent using your actual Tracking Consent Manager invocation and pass it to updateUserCOnsent function.
var consent = window.confirm("We need your consent for website tracking and cookie management. Click OK if you agree, otherwise close the site or click Cancel");

if(window.TrackingConsentManager) {
    window.TrackingConsentManager.updateUserConsent(consent);
}
```

The below screenshot shows the behaviour with the light-mode not allowing for tracking, with dark mode showing the result of approving tracking.

[image]

You can read more in the documentation [here](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/integrate-third-party-tracking-consent-manager), on how to configure Sitefinity with Google Tag Manager.

Hope that helps,
Jochem.